# MVC read txt file and set it on cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc

MVC:
I'm trying to read a rtf file in controller and put it in view.
Have someone experience with that kind of stuff?

kind regards

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is it throwing exceptions and 500ing, or failing silently?

Comment: can you post a code snippet?